# Looking for a Linux console keymap for a laptop with a Latinamerican keyboard layout

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard-layout

I hope this question is appropriate for this forum. I am in the process of installing arch linux on a samsung np300e5e laptop I bought new in Peru about 10 years ago.

This laptop has a Latinamerican keyboard layout (see: "Latin America, officially known as Spanish Latinamerican sort" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QWERTY_keyboard_language_variants). Arch's live installation system comes with several Spanish keyboard maps for the console (not worried about X yet), but unfortunately none match this keyboard.

I am aware that I can write my own map file, place it in /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/, and load it with loadkeys. However, if someone knows a ready-made file available somewhere I would be very grateful.

Googling around I found out that the file in question might be called "latam" something or other, but I had no luck finding the file itself. Surely such a file must exist, especially considering that this keyboard layout has been selling all over Latin America for decades (on windows systems mostly, but still).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.